# How to use horizontal and vertical scrolling together

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, scrolltop, vertical-scrolling

Here I have a code

```
<ul id="card-container">
    <li>
        <div class="card-wrap">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="card-wrap">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
</li>
```

I want the #card-container to be horizontally scrolled on mousewheel but if I hover on the .card-wrap and scroll with mousewheel the .card-wrap should scroll vertically.

Right now from my code both of the scrolls are taking place together.

```
 $('#card-container').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.card-wrap').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollTop -= (delta * 40);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Need some assistance.

Comment: Uh, how can you do it together? It could be only one direction as the scrollbar can scroll in one direction. You don't have a scroll ball! ☺

Answer (score 0):

One of my friend helped me out with this thus sharing it to you all.
Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('#card-container').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
     this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
     e.preventDefault();
 });
$('.card-wrap').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#card-container').unmousewheel();
});
$('.card-wrap').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#card-container').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Thanks.